# How-to Use credentials to connect til sql database

Tags: azure

I am using Azure Runbooks to automate updates to a SQLserver. I use insecure password in the runbooks, and would like to use Azure credentials to increase security.

In my Azure Automation account, I have created a credential with the SQLserver username and password.  But I haven’t been able to get the credential accessible in the runbook and into the invoke-sqlcmd command.

I have tried many variants of get-azureautomationcredentials, but seem to be running round in circles.

Does any of you have an example of working code from a runbook, getting til credential, and using it in invoke-sqlcmd.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am embarished :-)  The answer is very simple, and I don't know, why I count not get it to work.

The answer is:

```
$SQLcredential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'MySQLcredentials' 
$Results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $query -Server $SQLserver -database $SQLdatabase -Credential $SQLcredential -EncryptConnection
```